# Twitter BootStrap Background Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I have a fixed nav bar at the top and a container with a full width Background spanning span12. but since the content of the background image is crucial for the layout for visual cue. i want the whole image to be displayed at all times irrespective of the window size.

Which is the best way to construct the image or set of images to achieve the same.

**Large Monitor**

[image]

**Medium Monitor**

[image]

**Small Size**

[image]

I have a form that will be displayed to the right of the image. Hence making it a little tricky for me to get the image working.

Link: [play.mink7.com/minkstock/](http://play.mink7.com/minkstock/)

Comment: can you post a jsFiddle please?

Comment: @OliverAtkinson have added the link play.mink7.com/minkstock/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want just to have a maximum size (or percentage) that your image can reach.  Try, instead of a background image, using a `<img>` element like so:

```
img{
   max-width: 100%; /* or any other value */
   height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you chose to set the background image using css?

If i change the #landing-page-bg div to

```
<div id="landing-page-bg" style="background-image: none; width: auto; text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://play.mink7.com/minkstock/images/landing_page_bg.jpg">
</div>
```

It produces the desired effect you want (minus some red background you set).

If you wanted to then overlay items on the image you could use relative div positioning.

Comment: so if i have a full span12 at all times. will the large image change its size to fit correctly ?

Comment: @HarshaMV correct, the container class you put the row in is a fixed-responsive layout and has media queries to support its contents

Answer (score 1):

Do something like `background: url(images/landing_page_bg.jpg) 77% 0 fixed no-repeat;` for your small media query.